# C++11 - Move object containing filestream

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, fstream, move-semantics

I've got the following (simplified problem):

```
class Stream()
{ 
    std::ofstream mStr;
public:
    Stream() : mStr("file", ofstream::out)
    {}

    Stream(const Stream & rhs) = delete;

    Stream(Stream && rhs) : mStr(move(rhs.mStr))
    {}

    void operator()(string& data)
    {
        mStr << data;
    }

    ~Stream() = default;
};
```

The object is for logging purpose (measuring data) an will just be used for a short amount of time, so it's open as long as it is alive. The main idea now is to use it like that:

```
int main()
{
    std::function<void (std::string&)> Logger = Stream();
    for (std::string& data : DataList)
    {
        Logger(data);
    }
}
```

I've got to problems (GCC 4.7.2).

1. The `Stream` class needs to have a copy constructor, if I do that though it is not used.
2. I can't move the `fstream`.

Is this a compiler-problem or am i missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [cppreference.com.function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function):

> ```
> template< class F > 
> function( F f );
> ```
>
> The type `F` should be `CopyConstructible` and the object `f` should be `Callable`.

But your copy-constructor for `Stream` class is `deleted`:

```
Stream(const Stream & rhs) = delete;
```

---

> I can't move the `fstream`

This is a known issue with `libstdc++` library. The following code compiles fine with clang and `libc++`:

```
std::fstream f1, f2;
f2 = std::move(f1);
```

But fails with `libstdc++`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use a lambda function:

```
Stream s;
auto Logger = [&s] (std::string& data) {
    s(data);
};

for (std::string& data : DataList) {
    Logger(data);
}
```